# Google Maps API autocomplete inconsistency in country names

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are making requests to Google to get the coordinates and the country for specific cities and hotels.

We are using the autocomplete and for example:

"Amsterdam, The Netherlands"

[image]

We get the location reference = CkQyAAAAWv8eQqe4JnyaX6oGHP8SIq6eGIUrN6Jx8dFsOEcDn7OCLIRR-ZxucR5jg8P-FJtm6fgFkOjhxAUfzE6JL8un5xIQcN_hKzWaS6pUVCyt5xAjghoU1jfArNwwQRbTiu_ZxwBTzlnZr9Q

We make a call again to Google to get the coordinates and the country. This is the link

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CkQyAAAAWv8eQqe4JnyaX6oGHP8SIq6eGIUrN6Jx8dFsOEcDn7OCLIRR-ZxucR5jg8P-FJtm6fgFkOjhxAUfzE6JL8un5xIQcN_hKzWaS6pUVCyt5xAjghoU1jfArNwwQRbTiu_ZxwBTzlnZr9Q&sensor=false&key=[KEY]

We get this response

```
     {
        "long_name" : "Amsterdam",
        "short_name" : "Amsterdam",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Government of Amsterdam",
        "short_name" : "Government of Amsterdam",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "North Holland",
        "short_name" : "NH",
        "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "The Netherlands",
        "short_name" : "NL",
        "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
     }
```

We take the country by "long_name" : "The Netherlands" and we are happy but there comes this case:

We are using autocomplete for "Hotel luxer"

[image]

We get the location reference = ClRFAAAAzuaZS1YQuJOjjO3NH2rDIDrrJyiiyvmGVF90-WdZB-_mpjROO-a322bJQHYRRGVQTySPcCmpmgHYXCH9-useDg_EeRSX1tL9Igz9e1TuYcISEELfMqkiKHE5BuR7i3Y6fMYaFMXY5fk_psERzpGHesrRJhnO5gPl

We make the call again to Google, here is the link:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=ClRFAAAAzuaZS1YQuJOjjO3NH2rDIDrrJyiiyvmGVF90-WdZB-_mpjROO-a322bJQHYRRGVQTySPcCmpmgHYXCH9-useDg_EeRSX1tL9Igz9e1TuYcISEELfMqkiKHE5BuR7i3Y6fMYaFMXY5fk_psERzpGHesrRJhnO5gPl&sensor=false&key=[KEY]

This is the response

```
     {
        "long_name" : "11",
        "short_name" : "11",
        "types" : [ "street_number" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Warmoesstraat",
        "short_name" : "Warmoesstraat",
        "types" : [ "route" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Amsterdam",
        "short_name" : "Amsterdam",
        "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "Netherlands",
        "short_name" : "NL",
        "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
     },
     {
        "long_name" : "1012 HT",
        "short_name" : "1012 HT",
        "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
     }
```

We get the "long_name" : "Netherlands", even if the original autocomplete was with "The Netherlands".

Is there any option that we can set to be sure that we get a default name for the country?

Comment: What has this to do with google-bigquery tag?

Comment: There is no such option, when you want unique values supply them on your own, e.g. by using key-value pairs based on the country-code(`{NL:'The Netherlands',US:'United States'}` and so on)